# json.net handle strange format

Tags: c#, json.net

how i can handle with json.net this:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/VoiDGlitch/WarframeData/master/JSON/MissionDecks.json

These are the class:

```
class TennoItem
{
    public List<TennoData> Data { get; set; }
}



class TennoData
{
    [JsonProperty("Locations")]
    public string[] Locations { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Rotation A")]
    public string[] RotationA { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Rotation B")]
    public string[] RotationB { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Rotation C")]
    public List<string> RotationC { get; set; }


}
```

then

```
SERIALIZER.Deserialize<Dictionary<string,TennoItem>>(json_reader);
```

but i got string and null tennoitem

I see that Locations can be:

1."Locations" :null
2."Locations": [ string ]
3."Locations": ["string":"string"]

how can i handle this? with a custom converter?

suggestion?

Comment: Please post an [MCVE]. Also, did you mean [tag:c#]?

Comment: The problem starts at line 261, where you have the following: `{
    "Locations": [
      {
        "Neptune, THE INDEX": "ENDURANCE, MT_ARENA, FC_CORPUS, NT_SUB_MISSION"
      }
    ]}`  This location is an object, not a string.  How do you want to deserialize it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your base class inherit from dictionary:

```
class TennoItem : Dictionary<string, TennoData>
{

}
```

You should use List instead of array:

**Edit**:  dbc is correct, beginning line 261 the Location is an object. Try using object type:

```
class TennoData
{
    [JsonProperty("Locations")]
    public List<object> Locations { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Rotation A")]
    public List<string> RotationA { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Rotation B")]
    public List<string> RotationB { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Rotation C")]
    public List<string> RotationC { get; set; }    

}
```

and then:

```
SERIALIZER.Deserialize<TennoItem>(json_reader);
```

**or** **try** making Locations a dictionary object:

```
class TennoData
{
    [JsonProperty("Locations")]
    public List<Location> Locations { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Rotation A")]
    public List<string> RotationA { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Rotation B")]
    public List<string> RotationB { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Rotation C")]
    public List<string> RotationC { get; set; }    

}
class Location : Dictionary<string, string>
{
}
```